# Outdoor Faucet Leak

Tags: faucet, outdoor

[image]

Looking for some answers to a leaky faucet.   What type is this?...if it's leaking can it be repaired without cutting any water lines?...how would I access the washers or other rubber pieces?

All the faucets I saw others fixing on other sites didn't have the extra top piece.

I live in a mid latitude climate...thanks

Comment: Can you post a picture showing the faucet body? All we see here is the knob.

Comment: From the top?...there's a vacuum breaker up top

Comment: We need to see the faucet itself, what is behind the knob. Most spigots like this have a removable packing gland that is accessed by removing the knob but we can't see anything by your pic.

Comment: Just take the handle off via the visible screw then take another pic

Comment: I got the screw off, removed a plastic hex after that and a long metal tubing.  The hardware store didn't have the parts, but instead wants to sell me the whole thing.  Supposedly the whole spigot screws off with threading inside the house that I cannot see, but it doesn't seem to be doing that.